# Selenium Python cant get style from div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im having trouble getting the style of an element, anything I have tried I get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, heres my code:

```
        movingavg_one = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')).value_of_css_property('color')
        print(movingavg_one)
```

Heres the element [image]

I tried using getAttribute("style") and get_attribute("style") for some reason those also didn't work, im trying to get the color of the element, the element's color is the only thing that is in "style", so anything that will get the elements style will work. I have no idea what the problem is, but it's probably something really obvious that im missing.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By.XPATH('By.XPATH('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div') using java here? (By.XPATH, "xpath") is python.')
```

Using Java here?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath").value_of_css_property('color')
```

is the equivalent in Python.

Comment: Oh man, I knew it was something simple, haven't done any programming in a while, anyway, many thanks Arundeep Chohan, it now works as intended. All python, wasn't using any java, just a syntax error on my end.

Comment: No problem this question should have been answered a while back though.